SQL Update statement iterating through all rows in table
I have a script which iterates through a table and updates a specific column with a temp table generated a moment beforehand. However I was expecting it to only update the 20 or so rows in this case, and it ended up running for close to 3 hours before I killed it.
Below is an example of the code. To the best of my knowledge the issue is that the Update statement is not referencing the alias in the from clause. This causes the update statement to try and run through the entire table although it only runs an actual update when it comes across one of the connected values.
Update MasterTable
set FieldtoUpdate = b.TempFieldValue
from MasterTable a
join TempTable b on A.Pkey = b.Pkey


If the update has to sift through millions of records, it can still take some time despite only 20 records actually being updated.

Without table and index definitions, and the query plan (you can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) it's not answerable I'm afraid. Also SSMS is the client app you use, not the actual database. Please tag your actual DBMS.

What's the reason only 20 records will be updated? How large is TempTable?

and some other query might be locking the MasterTable; it could even be you on a different app/SSMS Query window.

I never figured out this syntax, you should do the update t set value= x.value from tabletoupdate t inner join othertable x on x.id = t.id one

Adding where FieldtoUpdate <> b.TempFieldValue may also help (assuming neither a nullable).

You could try adding:
where MasterTable.Pkey IN (select TempTable.Pkey)

Even better: make the join on a subquery (so first, subquery Mastertable with IN statement above and then join that result to the TempTable). Joining large sets is expensive.
